# Simultaneous diagonalization of $\frac{A+A^{*}}{2}$ and $(AA^{*})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, diagonalization, hermitian-matrices

[CONVEX AND CONCAVE FUNCTIONS OF SINGULAR
VALUES OF MATRIX SUMS](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/66-1/pjm-v66-n1-p30-p.pdf)

This question comes from the proof of theorem $2$ linked above.

The author firstly defines $|A|=(AA^{*})^\frac{1}{2}.$

If $H $ and $K$ are Hermitian matrices, the notation $H\le K$ means $K-H$ is a  positive semidefinite matrix.

Theorem $2$ is : Let A and B be square matrices, not necessarily
Hermitian. Then unitary matrices $U$ and $V$ exist such that
$$|A+B|\le U|A|U^{*}+V|B|V^{*}.$$

In one part of the proof,  the author claims :$$\frac{1}{2}(A+A^{*})\le U|A|U^{*}$$ for some unitary  $U$.

He also says :take  $U$ to be such that a unitary similarity simultaneously brings $\frac{1}{2}(A + A^{*})$ and $U|A|U^* = U(AA ^*)^\frac{1}{2}U^*$ into diagonal form with diagonal elements in nonincreasing order.

I think this may be a question about simultaneous diagonalization of $\frac{1}{2}(A + A^{*})$ and $(AA ^*)^\frac{1}{2}.$

But I don't konw how to proof that  $\frac{1}{2}(A + A^{*})$  and $ (AA ^*)^\frac{1}{2}$ can be simultaneously diagonalizable by a unitary matrix.

Thanks!

I give the proof of the author in the form of pictures. Between Equation $(6)$ and the theorem 2's proof is a proof of a lemma.
[image: Theorem 2]
[image: The author's proof]

Comment: What does $\leq$ mean?

Comment: @ V.S.e.H. Sorry, I forget to write it,  $H\le K$ means $K-H$ is a positive semidefinite matrix with $H$ and $K$ are Hermitian matrices.

Comment: Is it clear when $A$ is hermitian? Maybe the author just assumes $A$ is diagonalizable, in which case $U^\dagger A U = D$ where $D$ is diagonal and also $$U^\dagger (A+A^\dagger) U=D+D^\dagger$$ $$U^\dagger AA^\dagger U=U^\dagger AU U^\dagger A^\dagger U=DD^\dagger$$ is diagonal.

Comment: @Diger  No,the author says $A$ and $B$ are only  square matrices. I have added the author's proof in the form of a picture above.

Comment: Looks to me that they invoke the polar decomposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article does not claim that $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^*)$ and $(AA^*)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. What the article claims is that there exists a unitary $U$ such that $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^*)$ and $U(AA^*)^{\frac{1}{2}}U^*$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. The latter ist easy to see as
$$\frac{1}{2}(A+A^*) = V_1D_1V_1^* \quad \text{and} \quad (AA^*)^{\frac{1}{2}} = V_2D_2V_2^*$$
for some unitary $V_1,V_2$ and diagonal $D_1,D_2$. Now choose $U := V_1V_2^*$.

Comment: I misunderstand it. Thanks!